# Convertir timestamp a dd/mm/aaaa y sumar Timezone en Dataframe Panda

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

estoy carga información en un DataFramedel módulo Panda de Python, donde tengo un registro tipo timestamp, dicha información es traída desde MongoDb

```
cursor = collection.find( { "sono" : str(sono), "time" :  { "$gt" : int(start) }, "time" :{"$lt": int(end) }}, {"time" : 1, "timezone" : 1, "_id" :0 })
df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor),columns=['time','timezone'])
```

Luego cargo la información en el DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor),columns=['time','timezone'])
```

Luego convierto el tipo de dato timestamp a datetime:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

Ahora el problema es necesito sumar a la hora la columna timezone

La información que me despliega es:

```
                     time  timezone
0     2018-08-14 15:31:50        +3
1     2018-08-14 15:31:51        +3
2     2018-08-14 15:31:52        +3
3     2018-08-14 15:31:53        +3
4     2018-08-14 15:31:54        +3
5     2018-08-14 15:31:55        +3
```

Debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
                     time  timezone
0     2018-08-14 18:31:50        +3
1     2018-08-14 18:31:51        +3
2     2018-08-14 18:31:52        +3
3     2018-08-14 18:31:53        +3
4     2018-08-14 18:31:54        +3
5     2018-08-14 18:31:55        +3
```

Comment: Estás restando (15 - -3), no sumando (15 + -3) ¿Es un error o es lo que quieres¿

Comment: es un error, debería sumarle 3 horas, o dependiendo el dato que tenga el timestamp

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar simplemente [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) sobre la columna `timezone` especificando la unidad (horas).

Primero un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"time": ("2018-08-23 01:31:50",
                 "2018-08-14 23:31:51",
                 "2018-08-14 12:31:52",
                 "2018-08-14 15:31:53",
                 "2018-08-14 22:31:54",
                 "2018-08-14 17:31:55"),
        "timezone": (-2, 1, -1, -3, 2, 3)
        }


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
```

Con esto ya podemos hacer algo:

> ```
> >>> df
>                  time  timezone
> 0 2018-08-23 01:31:50        -2
> 1 2018-08-14 23:31:51         1
> 2 2018-08-14 12:31:52        -1
> 3 2018-08-14 15:31:53        -3
> 4 2018-08-14 22:31:54         2
> 5 2018-08-14 17:31:55         3
>
> >>> df["time"] += pd.to_timedelta(df.timezone, unit="h")
>
> >>> df
>                  time  timezone
> 0 2018-08-22 23:31:50        -2
> 1 2018-08-15 00:31:51         1
> 2 2018-08-14 11:31:52        -1
> 3 2018-08-14 12:31:53        -3
> 4 2018-08-15 00:31:54         2
> 5 2018-08-14 20:31:55         3
> ```

Comment: Era lo que intentaba hacer, gracias